# firebase : 401 unauthorized but login successful(fetching uid successfully)

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

my firebase app with auth as well with the rules set like this below.

```
{

"rules": {

".read": "auth!=null",

".write": "auth!=null",

}

}
```

#my html with AuthUI installed...

```
<body>
<h1>Welcome to My Awesome App</h1>
<div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>
<table id="developer_list"></table>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.4/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.4/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.5/firebase-database.js"></script>


<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.4/firebase-auth.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.8.0/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/4.8.0/firebase-ui-auth.css" />


<script>

var config = {apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "xxx.app",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx",
    appId: "xx:xxx:web:xxx",
    measurementId: "xxx-xxx"
};

/* firebase initializing */
firebase.initializeApp(config); 
const auth = firebase.auth();


auth.onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{console.log("Signed in!!!"+user.uid);});

var messagesRef = firebase.database().ref('forms');


fetch("https://xxx-xx-xx.xx-xx.firebasedatabase.app/xxx.json").then(res =>{res =res.json();return res;}).then(data=>{ for (let i in data){document.getElementById('developer_list').innerHTML += `
                    <tr>
              <!-- <span style="color:red"><td> id: ${i}</td></span>    -->
                        <span id="${i}" style="color:blue"><td> name: ${data[i].name} </td></span>
                        <td> job:  ${data[i].job} </td>
                        </br>
                    </tr>
                    `;}})

    var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
    
    ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
    
    signInOptions: [
    
    firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    
    ],
    
    
    
    signInSuccessUrl: './xyz.html',
    
    });


</script>
</body>
```

But it doesn't work!

I also inserted this snippet to keep track of auth status:

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{console.log("signed in!!"+user.uid);});
```

and of course after signing in with the code above it shows me "singed in!!" with my user uid correctly,

but still getting 401 unauthroized error.

What's the problem with the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply because the fetch logic's ULR and the purpose of doing so.

If you look at the code closely, the URL ends with .json and that was the main reason it was blocked. (Thank you for pointing that out, "samthecodingman")

If you get the database data from that URL it means you are trying to use REST API and other logic should be passed through(REST API's auth)

Normally, you should get your db data(unless you intend to resort to REST API) for your front end, you should use firebase's code logic(etc through CDN or js module files)

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your full project, this appears to be a race condition, you must prevent or pause your app before accessing your firebase resources as the user needs to finalize the authentication.

Depending on your framework, this could be a "useEffect" or handled through the app's state. But I cannot comment further without knowing more about your project

Comment: Currently, the OP is using the Web SDK & the REST API directly without any other frameworks and without signing the request. (Edit: I also just noticed this comment itself is a race condition, because the post was edited after your answer)

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. I provided the whole code. I just wanted to test it with vanilla JS code and the auth UI is set so that it should be redirected to another page which has the same code(so it's a duplicate page which already has the fetching db logic). But even after auth code snippet it doesn't work

Comment: @samthecodingman thank you! So my problem is due to the fact I am using Web SDK & Rest API directly& without signing request? I am just testing with vanilla js and didn't know there are other ways to achieve it other then web sdk. Could you please give me a hint at what other methods to take? thanks!